# openMP C++ simple parallel region - inconsistent output

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

As stated above, I have been trying to craft a simple parallel loop, but it has inconsistent behaviour for different number of threads. Here is my code (testable!)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int row = 5, col = 5;
int token = 1;

int ar[20][20] = {0};

int main (void)
{

    unsigned short j_end = 1, k = 1;
    unsigned short mask;

    for (unsigned short i=1; i<=(row + col -1); i++)
    {

        #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(ar) firstprivate(k, row, col, i, j_end, token) private(mask)
        {
            if(i > row) {
                mask = row;
            }
            else {
                mask = i;
            }

            #pragma omp for schedule(static, 2)
            for(unsigned short j=k; j<=j_end; j++)
            {
                ar[mask][j] = token;
                if(mask > 1) {
                    #pragma omp critical
                    {
                        mask--;
                    }
                }       
            } //inner loop - barrier

        }//end parallel

        token++;
        if(j_end == col) {                          
            k++;
            j_end = col;
        }
        else {
            j_end++;
        }

    } // outer loop

    // print the array
    for (int i = 0; i < row + 2; i++)
    {
       for (int j = 0; j < col + 2; j++)
       {
           cout << ar[i][j] << " ";
       }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
} // main
```

I believe most of the code is self explanatory, but to sum it up, I have 2 loops, the inner one iterates through the inverse-diagonals of the square matrix `ar[row][col]`, (`row` & `col` variables can be used to change the total size of `ar`).

Visual aid: desired output for 5x5 `ar` (serial version)
(Note: This does happen when `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` too.)

[image]

But when `OMP_NUM_THREADS=2` or `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` the output looks like this:

[image]

The serial (and for 1 thread) code is consistent so I don't think the implementation is problematic. Also, given the output of the serial code, there shouldn't be any dependencies in the inner loop.

I have also tried:

- Vectorizing
- threadpivate counters for the inner loop

But nothing seems to work so far...

Is there a fault in my approach, or did I miss something API-wise that led to this behavior?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: There's no reason to use `firstprivate` for read-only variables. A good rule of thumb is to always use shared for read-only variables.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Well, I thought it might increase the performance a little, since the price (in memory) is small, relatively to the time all the threads would need to constantly access the same variable - since they do access it some million times in total (for large matrices)

Comment: Good thought process. However, merely accessing memory does not cause thread contention. That only occurs if the memory being accessed has been changed by any of the other threads. Hence my advice to use `shared` for read-only variables.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Sound piece of info, but sadly, this does not solve my problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Analyzing the algorithm

As you noted, the algorithm itself has no dependencies in the inner *or* outer loop. An easy way to show this is to move the parallelism "up" to the outer loop so that you can iterate across all the different inverse diagonals simultaneously.

Right now, the main problem with the algorithm you've written is that it's presented as a serial algorithm in both the inner and outer loop. If you're going to parallelize across the inner loop, then `mask` needs to be handled specially. If you're going to parallelize across the outer loop, then `j_end`, `token`, and `k` need to be handled specially. By "handled specially," I mean they need to be computed independently of the other threads. If you try adding critical regions into your code, you will kill all performance benefits of adding OpenMP in the first place.

## Fixing the problem

In the following code, I parallelize over the outer loop. `i` corresponds to what you call `token`. That is, it is both the value to be added to the inverse diagonal and the assumed starting length of this diagonal. Note that for this to parallelize correctly, `length`, `startRow`, and `startCol` must be calculated as a function of `i` independently from other iterations.

Finally note that once the algorithm is re-written this way, the actual OpenMP pragma is incredibly simple. Every variable is assumed to be shared by default because they're all read-only. The only exception is `ar` in which we are careful never to overwrite another thread's value of the array. All variables that must be private are only created inside the parallel loop and thus are thread-private by definition. Lastly, I've changed the schedule to dynamic to showcase that this algorithm exhibits load-imbalance. In your example if you had 9 threads (the worst case scenario), you can see how the thread assigned to `i=5` has to do much more work than the thread assigned to `i=1` or `i=9`.

## Example code

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <omp.h>

int row = 5;
int col = 5;

#define MAXSIZE 20
int ar[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE] = {0};

int main(void)
{

    // What an easy pragma!

    #pragma omp parallel for default(shared) schedule(dynamic)
    for (unsigned short i = 1; i < (row + col); i++)
    {
        // Calculates the length of the current diagonal to consider
        // INDEPENDENTLY from other i iterations!
        unsigned short length = i;
        if (i > row) {
            length -= (i-row);
        }
        if (i > col) {
            length -= (i-col);
        }

        // Calculates the starting coordinate to start at
        // INDEPENDENTLY from other i iterations!
        unsigned short startRow = i;
        unsigned short startCol = 1;
        if (startRow > row) {
            startCol += (startRow-row);
            startRow = row;
        }

        for(unsigned short offset = 0; offset < length; offset++) {
            ar[startRow-offset][startCol+offset] = i;    
        }

    } // outer loop

    // print the array
    for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++)
    {
       for (int j = 0; j <= col; j++)
       {
           std::cout << ar[i][j] << " ";
       }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
} // main
```

## Final points

I want to leave with a few last points.

- If you are only adding parallelism on a small array (`row,col < 1e6`), you will most likely not get any benefits from OpenMP. On a small array, the algorithm itself will take microseconds, while setting up the threads could take milliseconds... slowing down execution time considerably from your original serial code!
- While I did rewrite this algorithm and change around variable names, I tried to keep the spirit of your implementation as best as I could. Thus, the inverse-diagonal scanning and nested loop pattern remains.
- There is a better way to parallelize this algorithm to avoid load balance, though. If instead you give each thread a row and have it instead iterate its token value (i.e. row/thread 2 places the numbers 2->6), then each thread will work on exactly the same amount of numbers and you can change the pragma to `schedule(static)`.
- As I mentioned in the comments above, don't use `firstprivate` when you mean `shared`. A good rule of thumb is that all read-only variables should be `shared`.
- It is erroneous to assume that getting correct output when running parallel code on 1 thread implies the implementation is correct. In fact, barring disastrous use of OpenMP, you are incredibly unlikely to get the wrong output with only 1 thread. Testing with multiple threads reveals that your previous implementation was not correct.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: The output I get is [the same as yours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyEAQ.png) for a 5x5 matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, although the snippet you originally provided doesn't work properly. I tried to execute this, but I'm getting compiler errors.. Also, shouldn't there be a #pragma omp for somewhere? otherwise the for loop won't be parallelized right?

Comment: @Mechanic indeed there was a typo. I left out the `#include <omp.h>` and `pragma omp for`. What compiler errors are you getting exactly?

Comment: This was the generated error: ‘schedule’ is not valid for ‘#pragma omp parallel’
     #pragma omp parallel default(shared) schedule(dynamic)
Although now you fixed it.

Comment: Also, can you include a screenshot of the output? because when I run it (with the new fixes) differs greately, from what I decribed above

Comment: When I give it `row=5,col=5` I get your exact [image posted above](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oyEAQ.png)...

Comment: @Mechanic OK my bad. There was in fact one last typo... I mistyped col as row. Now it should be the correct output.